# Installing and using version 1 of google cloud trace api client for python

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-python, google-cloud-trace

I'm trying to write a script to extract Stackdriver Trace information to load into big query and I'm having trouble installing the python client library. I need version 1 of the library to access the data, but when I install google-cloud-trace it defaults to version 2.

The instructions at https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/trace/index.html suggest I should install a package called gapic-google-cloud-trace-v1, but this doesn't seem to exist.

Is there a way to access version 1 through the client, is there another package or should I just give up and use http directly?

Answer (score 1):

Should have read more careful, the installation instructions make no sense, but further down it says you can access it via `import google.cloud.trace_v1`